# Google Analytics Data for Particular page

Tags: google-analytics-api

I have integrated Google Analytics. I want to fetch the data for a particuar page. I have got data for many pages. But I am not getting data for some pages I need. Though, that page is shown in Google Analytics Reporting area. Can anyone suggest the reason ?

```
$params = array( 'metrics' => 'ga:visits,ga:socialInteractions,ga:pageviews,ga:bounces,ga:uniquePageviews' , 'dimensions' => 'ga:pagePath' , 'ga:pagePath=@/c14z8', ); 
$visits = $ga->query($params);
```

Comment: I think you need to help us a bit more. Code maybe or what it is exactly that you are doing.  As it is now it is hard to figure out what it is you are asking.

Comment: Below is the code
`$params = array(
           'metrics'    => 'ga:visits,ga:socialInteractions,ga:pageviews,ga:bounces,ga:uniquePageviews',
           'dimensions' => 'ga:pagePath',
'ga:pagePath=@/c14z8',
       );
       
       $visits = $ga->query($params);`

I am getting many other URLs but not what I need.

Comment: That last part is that meant to be a filter?  What client lib are you using?

Comment: Sorry, but it seems you are saying two different things: You can't find data for a particular page, but the page is shown in the reporting area. Please clarify. For data to be collected for any page of your site, you must have the tracking properly implemented and there must be visits to that page already. If that is true, then you can find page reports under Behvaviour > Site Content > All Pages, and you should find the page you are looking for (you can even filter by the specific page as well using the search bar).